# How to sort select alphabetically which contains optgroup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have the following Bootstrap SelectPicker. I would like to sort all the `option` and `optgroup` alphabetically. My code doesn't seem to be working on the SelectPicker nor on a normal `select`. Does someone know how to do this?

```js
var options = $('select option');
var arr = options.map(function(_, o) { return { t: $(o).text(), v: o.value }; }).get();
arr.sort(function(o1, o2) { return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0; });
options.each(function(i, o) {
  o.value = arr[i].v;
  $(o).text(arr[i].t);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="property-area" name="property_area" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-primary btn-round" data-live-search="true" tabindex="-98">
  <option value="1208">Amalfi Coast</option>
  <option value="1224">Apulia</option>
  <optgroup data-id="1221" label="Tuscany">
    <option value="1302" data-parent-id="1221">Arezzo</option>
    <option value="1299" data-parent-id="1221">Argentario</option>
    <option value="1270" data-parent-id="1221">Chianti</option>
    <option value="1261" data-parent-id="1221">Florence</option>
    <option value="1297" data-parent-id="1221">Lucca &amp; Pisa</option>
    <option value="1290" data-parent-id="1221">Maremma</option>
    <option value="1283" data-parent-id="1221">Siena</option>
    <option value="1330" data-parent-id="1221">Val D'Orcia</option>
  </optgroup>
  <option value="1213">Capri Island</option>
  <option value="1249">Cilento Coast</option>
  <option value="1215">Como Lake</option>
  <option value="1253">Garda Lake</option>
  <option value="1334">Ischia Island</option>
  <option value="1257">Maggiore Lake</option>
  <option value="1234">Rome City</option>
  <option value="1308">Sicily</option>
  <option value="1205">Sorrento Coast</option>
  <option value="1218">Umbria</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How did you apply that sort to the `option`s?

Comment: @freedomn-m I updated the snippet

Comment: I've added jquery to the snippet so that it runs and taken the liberty of removing the `.whatever` selector so that it finds your `select` (or could have added `class='whatever'` - sorting is now applied.  Can you provide details regarding how it doesn't do what you want (what's your expected output vs what it does do).  eg if you want the items in the optgroup excluded from the main sort

Comment: @freedomn-m I see thanks, essentially the result returned is wrong 'cause `Tuscany` should be placed between after `Sorrento`

Comment: Ah, so you need the `optgroup` sorted with the top level `option`s

Comment: @freedomn-m yes, seems only options are sorted alphabetically but for some reason the `optgroup` is skipped

Comment: First thing to change is `$("select option")` to `$("select>option")` so the sub items don't get sorted, then apply a 2nd sort to move the optgroups

Comment: *"optgroup is skipped"* - because your selector uses `select option` and `optgroup` is not an `option`.  You can't use the same sort because you're changing values+text rather than sorting DOM nodes.

Comment: @freedomn-m could you please show me an example? I can't get it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with vanilla JS like this. I placed some of the last items in the dropdown as the first items, just to demonstrate.

If you give all of them labels then you can do it like this:

```js
function sortStuff(arr) {
  arr.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.label < b.label) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a.label > b.label) {
      return 1
    }
    return 0;
  })
  return arr
}

var select = document.querySelector('select')
var options = [...select.children]
var sortedOptions = sortStuff(options)

select.innerHTML = ''
sortedOptions.forEach(i => select.append(i))
sortedOptions[0].setAttribute('selected', 'true')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="property-area" name="property_area" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-primary btn-round" data-live-search="true" tabindex="-98">
  <option value="1218" label="Umbria">Umbria</option>
  <option value="1205" label="Sorrento Coast">Sorrento Coast</option>
  <option value="1208" label="Amalfi Coast">Amalfi Coast</option>
  <option value="1224" label="Apulia">Apulia</option>
  <optgroup data-id="1221" label="Tuscany">
    <option value="1302" data-parent-id="1221">Arezzo</option>
    <option value="1299" data-parent-id="1221">Argentario</option>
    <option value="1270" data-parent-id="1221">Chianti</option>
    <option value="1261" data-parent-id="1221">Florence</option>
    <option value="1297" data-parent-id="1221">Lucca &amp; Pisa</option>
    <option value="1290" data-parent-id="1221">Maremma</option>
    <option value="1283" data-parent-id="1221">Siena</option>
    <option value="1330" data-parent-id="1221">Val D'Orcia</option>
  </optgroup>
  <option value="1213" label="Capri Island">Capri Island</option>
  <option value="1249" label="Cilento Coast">Cilento Coast</option>
  <option value="1215" label="Como Lake">Como Lake</option>
  <option value="1253" label="Garda Lake">Garda Lake</option>
  <option value="1334" label="Ischia Island">Ischia Island</option>
  <option value="1257" label="Maggiore Lake">Maggiore Lake</option>
  <option value="1234" label="Rome City">Rome City</option>
  <option value="1308" label="Sicily">Sicily</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the result is not correct, as you can see from the snippet is not order alphabetically

Comment: For sure @sfarzoso . I realised that too, soooo I updated the answer and now it will put Tuscany in the right place. Try it out =) You just need to give all of them labels

Comment: Yebo yes I did. Maybe just do a refresh?? I see Tuscany as second last—right before Umbria

Comment: check this: https://imgur.com/a/rvR9e4h could you create a fiddle outside so?

Comment: Ohhhh yeah I see what you mean. I wrote it so it will only `console.log()` the right order, not physically reorder it—just to give you the formula. But I can edit it to make it physically work for the dropdown

Comment: Okay @sfarzoso , sorry for all the back and forth. It's physically rearranging them in the dropdown now, so it should be working perfectly.